# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0 and some time my appcrash and some time work properly

Tags: android, indexoutofboundsexception

Error:

> 03-28 14:23:08.466 8743-8743/com.furbonics.furbonicsexecutive
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                   Process: com.furbonics.furbonicsexecutive, PID: 8743
>                                                                                   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
>                                                                                       at
>   java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
>                                                                                       at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
>                                                                                       at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getItem(ArrayAdapter.java:337)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:390)
>                                                                                       at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
>                                                                                       at android.widget.Spinner.makeView(Spinner.java:592)
>                                                                                       at android.widget.Spinner.layout(Spinner.java:540)
>                                                                                       at android.widget.Spinner.onLayout(Spinner.java:502)
>                                                                                       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14845)
>                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>                                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1660)
>                                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
>                                                                                       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14845)
>                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>                                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
>                                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
>                                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
>                                                                                       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14845)
>                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>                                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
>                                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
>                                                                                       at android.widget.ScrollView.onLayout(ScrollView.java:1468)
>                                                                                       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14845)
>                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>                                                                                       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
>                                                                                       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14845)
>                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>                                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
>                                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
>                                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
>                                                                                       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14845)
>                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>                                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
>                                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
>                                                                                       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14845)
>                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>                                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
>                                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
>                                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
>                                                                                       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14845)
>                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>                                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
>                                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
>                                                                                       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14845)
>                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>                                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
>                                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
>                                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
>                                                                                       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14845)
>                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>                                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
>                                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
>                                                                                       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14845)
>                                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>                                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2026)
>                                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1783)
>                                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1039)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5648)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
>                                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
>                                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>                                                                                     at android.o

Comment: are you using recyclerview?

Comment: You have an empty  arrayList which has 0 items and You call the first item arrayList.get(0) . You should check  your list's size .

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to read a value from an empty array

> lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0.

Verify that the array is not empty before accessing a value in your code.

Answer (score 0):

It means you are not able to fetch data. First use log and check if output is shown if no then check your code also surround your code for fetching with try and catch.